# Fill Pandas dataframe based on conditions from same row values (based on Excel COUNTIFS formula)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like the following, and I want to fill a new column based on conditions from other columns. In this case:

- Having the same value in Cond1
- Amount being different than zero
- Being from previous months

Column "CountPreviousMonth" is what I need to fill out

| Cond1 | Amount | Month | CountPreviousMonth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 10 | 1 | 0 |
| a | 20 | 2 | 1 |
| a | 15 | 3 | 2 |
| b | 10 | 1 | 0 |
| b | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| b | 15 | 3 | 1 |
| c | 5 | 1 | 0 |
| c | 25 | 2 | 1 |
| c | 15 | 3 | 2 |

When month is 1 then the count is zero because is the first one.
In Cond1=b it stays at count = 1 because in Month 2 the Amount was zero

In Excel I used COUNTIFS but would like to do it in Python, where I could do it in a for loop but the real table has many rows and it wouldn't be efficient. Is there a better way to calculate it?

Answer (score 1):

First replace `Month` to missing values if `Amount=0` ant hen use custom lambda function with [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and forward filling missing values:

```
f = lambda x: x.shift(fill_value=0).ffill().astype(int)
df['count'] = df['Month'].mask(df['Amount'].eq(0)).groupby(df['Cond1']).transform(f)
print (df)
  Cond1  Amount  Month  CountPreviousMonth  count
0     a      10      1                   0      0
1     a      20      2                   1      1
2     a      15      3                   2      2
3     b      10      1                   0      0
4     b       0      2                   1      1
5     b      15      3                   1      1
6     c       5      1                   0      0
7     c      25      2                   1      1
8     c      15      3                   2      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Move down by 1, and check which ones are not equal to 0:

```py
arr = df.Amount.shift().ne(0)
```

Get boolean where month is 1:

```py
repl = df.Month.eq(1)
```

index arr with repl, to keep track of first month per group:

```py
arr[repl] = True
```

Groupby, run a cumulative sum, and finally deduct 1, to ensure every group starts at 0:

```py
df.assign(CountPreviousMonth = arr.groupby(df.Cond1).cumsum().sub(1))
  Cond1  Amount  Month  CountPreviousMonth
0     a      10      1                   0
1     a      20      2                   1
2     a      15      3                   2
3     b      10      1                   0
4     b       0      2                   1
5     b      15      3                   1
6     c       5      1                   0
7     c      25      2                   1
8     c      15      3                   2
```